# How to turn on gcc warnings for a forgotten return statement?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

How do I turn on gcc warnings for a forgotten return statement?

It is supposed to warn me in cases like the following:

```
int foo() {
  std::cout << "haha";
}
```

I know `-Wall` turns that warning on, but it enables too many other warnings.

Comment: Did you try -Wextra / -ansi / -pedantic?

Comment: `-Wall` enables too many other warnings? That's a first.

Comment: If you have -Wall turning on too many, an alternative would be to switch of the particular ones that are not conforming to your coding style. Although I would be curious to hear which ones you have that don't give you valuable feedback about problems in your code.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt:  Another possibility would be to rewrite the code to cut down on numbers of warnings.  Having code that compiles with a lot of error checking turned on but no warnings is very useful.  It is a lot easier to keep it that way than to get it that way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to gcc's [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), `-Wall` turns on:

```
      -Waddress   
      -Warray-bounds (only with -O2)  
      -Wc++0x-compat  
      -Wchar-subscripts  
      -Wenum-compare (in C/Objc; this is on by default in C++) 
      -Wimplicit-int (C and Objective-C only) 
      -Wimplicit-function-declaration (C and Objective-C only) 
      -Wcomment  
      -Wformat   
      -Wmain (only for C/ObjC and unless -ffreestanding)  
      -Wmissing-braces  
      -Wnonnull  
      -Wparentheses  
      -Wpointer-sign  
      -Wreorder   
      -Wreturn-type  
      -Wsequence-point  
      -Wsign-compare (only in C++)  
      -Wstrict-aliasing  
      -Wstrict-overflow=1  
      -Wswitch  
      -Wtrigraphs  
      -Wuninitialized  
      -Wunknown-pragmas  
      -Wunused-function  
      -Wunused-label     
      -Wunused-value     
      -Wunused-variable  
      -Wvolatile-register-var
```

Out of those, `-Wreturn-type` seems like it would do the trick:

> Warn whenever a function is defined with a return-type that defaults to int. Also **warn about any return statement with no return-value in a function whose return-type is not void (falling off the end of the function body is considered returning without a value)**, and about a return statement with an expression in a function whose return-type is void.

However, if turning on `-Wall` makes your code have way too many warnings, I'd recommend fixing up your code!

Answer (score -1):

always use:

gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall  -o